# How do I let walls have a minimum width?

Tags: 3d-printing

I am designing a 3D printable object. From a pure design perspective, many elements are extruded triangles. The problem is that the triangle will be very thin on the sharp edge.

For printing the object with a 3D printer, I need a minimum width, otherwise it will be interpreted as nothing and not become printed.

Basically, I need the following:

[image: Expected and unexpected]

- red: object as designed, not suitable for 3D printing
- green: minimum wall thickness, suitable for 3D printing

For this example I went into edit mode, added vertices manually and moved them manually until it looked like a minimum width. The result needn't look exactly like this. Actually I don't exactly know an algorithm to do that.

Note that I need to ensure that wall thickness on the whole scene, not only on a primitive object.

I have tried:

- the solidify modifier, but it still generates a sharp edge

Comment: Suggestion.  You may want to show your models in wireframe mode.  What tools in Blender have you used to help you with minimum thickness?

Comment: @atomicbezierslinger: for this example I went into edit mode, added vertices manually and moved them manually until it looked like a minimum width